# FindPostgreSQL.cmake won't work on ubuntu

Tags: cmake, libpq

- Ubuntu 12.04
- CMake 2.8.9
- Postgresql 9.2.2

I'm trying to get the `FindPostgreSQL` module to find `/usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h`.

Here's what I have in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)
```

This is the error I get:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find PostgreSQL (missing: PostgreSQL_TYPE_INCLUDE_DIR) (found
  version "9.2.2")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPostgreSQL.cmake:155 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

I added the following lines before calling `find_package` but it didn't seem to have any effect.

```
set(PostgreSQL_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "9.2.2")
set(PostgreSQL_ADDITIONAL_SEARCH_PATHS ${PostgreSQL_ADDITIONAL_SEARCH_PATHS} "/usr/include/postgresql")
```

I also tried googling for `PostgreSQL_TYPE_INCLUDE_DIR` but didn't find anything. What else can I try?

Comment: For anyone getting this error it also happens when you have `libpq-dev` installed but not `postgresql-server-dev-9.3`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Make sure you've installed both `libpq-dev\` and `postgresql-server-dev-all` (or specific version e.g. `postgresql-server-dev-9.4`)

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep -e "libpq-dev\|postgresql-server-dev"
```

in case you're missing some package

```
apt-get install libpq-dev postgresql-server-dev-all
```

should fix it.

Comment: Worked for me. Much nicer than editing a `.cmake` file!

Comment: This was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu you can also work around that issue by calling `cmake` with having `PostgreSQL_TYPE_INCLUDE_DIR` defined like this:

```
cmake -DPostgreSQL_TYPE_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/postgresql/
```

See the bug report [1] for this issue and a potential fix [2]. Álso see the discussion about the reasoning behind the move on the debian mailinglist at [3].

On Ubuntu/Debian, starting with PostgreSQL 9.3 the header file `pg_type.h`
is moved to a separate package (from `libpq-dev` to `postgresql-server-dev`)
and consequently the file `pg_type.h` is moved to a new location

- [1] https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17223
- [2] https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/d4fd30d8d8f5b9c4b5a110b4676cad2a19d7c314
- [3] https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=314427

Answer (score 7):

After a bit more debugging I figured out that it's getting stuck trying to find `pg_type.h`

This file is located in `/usr/include/postgresql/catalog/pg_types.h` but the module is expecting to find it in `/usr/include/postgresql/server/catalog/pg_types.h`

```
find_path(PostgreSQL_TYPE_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAMES catalog/pg_type.h
  PATHS
   # Look in other places.
   ${PostgreSQL_ROOT_DIRECTORIES}
  PATH_SUFFIXES
    pgsql/server
    postgresql/server
    include/server
  # Help the user find it if we cannot.
  DOC "The ${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIR_MESSAGE}"
)
```

It works if I add `postgresql` to the `PATH_SUFFIXES`

```
find_path(PostgreSQL_TYPE_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAMES catalog/pg_type.h
  PATHS
   # Look in other places.
   ${PostgreSQL_ROOT_DIRECTORIES}
  PATH_SUFFIXES
    postgresql
    pgsql/server
    postgresql/server
    include/server
  # Help the user find it if we cannot.
  DOC "The ${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIR_MESSAGE}"
)
```

Comment: This almost helps me.  Cmake runs but it doesn't seem to set up the include directory paths correctly.  Are you having issues with your source code not finding `libpq-fe.h`?  I'm disappointed that PostgreSQL is so problematic.

Comment: @johnzachary It's working for me. Where does your `libpq-fe.h` live?

Comment: To help anyone else running into this:  Since I first didn't understand, just wanted to point out this change is needed not in our own CMake files, but to the following CMake module: /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPostgreSQL.cmake. Around line #119 for cmake 2.8.9.

Comment: @Stéphane yes I should have clarified that.

Answer (score 2):

From Linux Mint 17.3 ("Rosa") with PostgreSQL 9.3, I had to adjust ilia choly's solution (interestingly, the suggested `postgres` entry in the list was already present in the file, but wasn't enough to fix things).

I had to edit `/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPostgreSQL.cmake` around line 114 and add `postgresql/9.3` so that the `find_path` call looks like

```
find_path(PostgreSQL_TYPE_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAMES catalog/pg_type.h
  PATHS
   # Look in other places.
   ${PostgreSQL_ROOT_DIRECTORIES}
  PATH_SUFFIXES
    postgresql/9.3
    postgresql
    pgsql/server
    postgresql/server
    include/server
  # Help the user find it if we cannot.
  DOC "The ${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIR_MESSAGE}"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Package managers on different systems use own locations to install PostgreSQL. CMakePostgreSQL.cmake has the list of locations, but it cannot include everything. Instead it has the description on lines 80-90 how to solve this issue:

```
# If you have installed PostgreSQL in a non-standard location.
# (Please note that in the following comments, it is assumed that <Your Path>
# points to the root directory of the include directory of PostgreSQL.)
# Then you have three options.
# 1) After CMake runs, set PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIR to <Your Path>/include and
#    PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIR to wherever the library pq (or libpq in windows) is
# 2) Use CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH to set a path to <Your Path>/PostgreSQL<-version>. This will allow find_path()
#    to locate PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIR by utilizing the PATH_SUFFIXES option. e.g. In your CMakeLists.txt file
#    set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "<Your Path>/include")
# 3) Set an environment variable called ${PostgreSQL_ROOT} that points to the root of where you have
#    installed PostgreSQL, e.g. <Your Path>.
```

In my case it resolves all problems by setting PostgreSQL_ROOT environment variable:

```
export PostgreSQL_ROOT=/usr/local/pgsql
cmake ..
```

Just point to your PostgreSQL root (directory where bin, include,lib are located), and it should work.