# Override CMake Find_Package

Tags: cmake

CMake module FindPostgreSQL.cmake that comes with Ubuntu and Debian [have issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920383/findpostgresql-cmake-wont-work-on-ubuntu) when you use find_package with PostGreSQL. We have a product that needs that and the best we can do is to ship our own version of FindPostgreSQL.cmake.

How can I then override CMake's FindPostgreSQL.cmake with our own without disturbing anything else? The project is found on [this github repository](https://github.com/mtangoo/wxDatabase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put them into `cmake/modules` directory of my project.

> CMake searches for a file called `Find<package>.cmake` in the
>   `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` followed by the CMake installation. If the file is
>   found, it is read and processed by CMake.

From CMake documentation find_package: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html